# Erro convertendo com DuoCode usando WinForms

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, conversão

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em C# usando Windows Forms, mas queria converter para JavaScript usando o DuoCode. Mas está dando os seguintes erros:

```
tryduocode.cs(7,14,7,21): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

tryduocode.cs(32,18,32,29): error CS1061: 'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'btnTraduzir' and no extension method 'btnTraduzir' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Talvez eu devesse usar Console ao invés de Windows Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esquece isto, o DuoCode faz muita coisa, mas não faz milagre. Ele só consegue converter aplicações triviais que operações na memória e pouco mais que isto. Surpreendentemente ele até consegue converter alguma coisa simples que faz IO (entra e saída) mas bem pouca. Não dá para pegar uma aplicação usando Windows Forms e tentar converter para rodar em um navegador.

Não sei se mudar para console vai te ajudar alguma coisa. Se você pode ficar ajustando sua aplicação desta forma, então não precisa desse conversor.

Ele foi feito para converter algumas poucas coisas, em geral funções de validação e algumas operações de manipulação de dados. Não foi feito para converter aplicações inteiras.

Deve existir um bom motivo para usá-lo. Ele não é uma varinha mágica que soluciona todos os problemas.

Comment: É, você está certo. Fiz algumas modificações. Tirei toda a referência de Windows Forms. Troquei as TextBox para variáveis públicas. Consegui fazer a conversão. Era mais mesmo para ter ideia de como escrever o mesmo código no javaScript. É só um programa que lê uma frase e envia para uma função caractere por caractere e diz o significado de cada letra. Muito obrigado.

Comment: A conversão não é feita para o código ser legível em JS, é só para funcionar lá. Não time isto como base. Cada linguagem tem sua particularidade e você deve programar nela do jeito dela.